# Add a co-routine delay before firing a process

Tags: php

Suppose that I have a login script for my website admin area, and suppose that each time someone logs in, a notification email is sent to various admin email addresses, informing them of this (rather like WordPress seems to do).

Now, suppose for varying reasons I want the login to be run as normal but the email notification to be sent some time later, such as 2 minutes later.

Obviously PHP has the `sleep` function but this holds up *all* page processing;  including -in this example situation- the user login will be "suspended" for a few minutes and login will only be completed once the sleep time expires and the email is sent.

- **Is there a way of achieving this (or similar) co-routine execution delay in PHP?**

> *I suspect not, but thought it is worth asking but I suspect the structure of PHP means it's unable to handle adding a delay only to a co-routine rather than to the whole thread process.*

Comment: The usual approach is to have a service running in the background. There're even PHP libraries that work on top of Unix cron.

Comment: ok, what are these services called? I figured Cron would be a possible method but I also feel that cron settings are often not easy to dynamicaly generate

Comment: cron is just a task scheduler. The hard part is writing a PHP command-line script that checks for pending messages, takes care of sending them and does not send them twice if executions overlap. Scheduling it to run every X minutes is trivial; many hosting providers ever have a nice control panel.

Comment: Another dirty hack could be to issue a system call to the nohup Unix command (all my advice assumes you are using some Unix flavour).

Comment: Yes it's a Debian server. I understand how cron jobs work but I figured it's somewhat fiddly to dynamically set the con job execution time (login time + 2 mins), but it's something I'm still exploring..

Comment: Ah... We're talking about **scheduling**, not **delaying**. You use cron to make the script execute every X minutes and the script just exits when nothing need to be done.

Comment: My only other thought was to use a database to record a time threshold (ie login+ 120 seconds), but that adds a whole level of interface complexity for something that on other programming languages (C#) is tediously simple

Comment: Cheers for all your comments so far on this, I'm gradualy forming a method of approach for my needs. Cheers @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You use cron to make the script execute every X minutes and the script just exits when nothing need to be done.

-- [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%c3%81lvaro-gonz%c3%a1lez)

So I set a cron job to run every 5 minutes and checking the database for recent logins (within last few minutes) and emailing the associated email address when this is detected.

Downside is that this will obviously make a MySQL call every few minutes. (*But I think the inefficiencies of this are pretty negligable*).